Blurring already drawn objects raylib?
I'm currently working on the menu for a game in raylib where I want to have the below function to be able to be blurred after it is drawn (meaning, after calling the function).
void drawBoard(Color lineColor, Color boardColor){
  ClearBackground(Color(boardColor));

  DrawRectangleV( (Vector2){294, 100}, (Vector2){7, 600}, Color(lineColor));
  DrawRectangleV( (Vector2){494, 100}, (Vector2){7, 600}, Color(lineColor));

  DrawRectangle(100, 294, 600, 7, Color(lineColor));
  DrawRectangle(100, 494, 600, 7, Color(lineColor));
}



I've searched around for ways to turn routines like this into textures (which I know how to blur) but haven't stumbled upon anything useful.
Please excuse my lack of knowledge in shaders and all.

Doing better than me. Usually I get blurring without trying and where I don't want it.

https://www.raylib.com/examples/shaders/loader.html?name=shaders_postprocessing - there is a blur example here.

I believe the example draws to a texture first, which is what I'm asking about, since I want to turn the function above into a Texture2D object to then throw the shader ont
